# Body Text Affected in using txfonts package

Tags: fonts

I don't want to use txfonts package because the Body will be affected. I just want to declare the correct font that being use by `\varmathbb` tag/code but I did not fount it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}
%\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\varmathbb}{letters}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
$\mathds{R}$


$\mathbb{R}$


$\varmathbb{R}$ -output should look this by not using the txfonts package.

\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean by “correct”? I usually use `\usepackage{dsfont}` and `\mathds{A}` for a different double-struck font.

Comment: Try to check the new code I presented.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to complement Heiko's answer, here's a simpler implementation with `xparse` and `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclareSymbolFont{lettersA}{U}{txmia}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{lettersA}{bold}{U}{txmia}{bx}{it}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{txmia}{m}{it}

\makeatletter
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rA}{\mathord}{lettersA}{129}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rB}{\mathord}{lettersA}{130}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rC}{\mathord}{lettersA}{131}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rD}{\mathord}{lettersA}{132}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rE}{\mathord}{lettersA}{133}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rF}{\mathord}{lettersA}{134}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rG}{\mathord}{lettersA}{135}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rH}{\mathord}{lettersA}{136}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rI}{\mathord}{lettersA}{137}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rJ}{\mathord}{lettersA}{138}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rK}{\mathord}{lettersA}{139}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rL}{\mathord}{lettersA}{140}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rM}{\mathord}{lettersA}{141}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rN}{\mathord}{lettersA}{142}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rO}{\mathord}{lettersA}{143}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rP}{\mathord}{lettersA}{144}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rQ}{\mathord}{lettersA}{145}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rR}{\mathord}{lettersA}{146}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rS}{\mathord}{lettersA}{147}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rT}{\mathord}{lettersA}{148}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rU}{\mathord}{lettersA}{149}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rV}{\mathord}{lettersA}{150}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rW}{\mathord}{lettersA}{151}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rX}{\mathord}{lettersA}{152}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rY}{\mathord}{lettersA}{153}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rZ}{\mathord}{lettersA}{154}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\varmathbb}{m}
 {
  \tl_map_inline:nn { #1 } { \use:c { m@thbbch@r##1 } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
$\varmathbb{ABC}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The relevant code for `\varmathbb` of package `txfonts`:

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareSymbolFont{lettersA}{U}{txmia}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{lettersA}{bold}{U}{txmia}{bx}{it}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{txmia}{m}{it}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rA}{\mathord}{lettersA}{129}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rB}{\mathord}{lettersA}{130}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rC}{\mathord}{lettersA}{131}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rD}{\mathord}{lettersA}{132}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rE}{\mathord}{lettersA}{133}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rF}{\mathord}{lettersA}{134}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rG}{\mathord}{lettersA}{135}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rH}{\mathord}{lettersA}{136}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rI}{\mathord}{lettersA}{137}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rJ}{\mathord}{lettersA}{138}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rK}{\mathord}{lettersA}{139}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rL}{\mathord}{lettersA}{140}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rM}{\mathord}{lettersA}{141}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rN}{\mathord}{lettersA}{142}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rO}{\mathord}{lettersA}{143}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rP}{\mathord}{lettersA}{144}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rQ}{\mathord}{lettersA}{145}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rR}{\mathord}{lettersA}{146}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rS}{\mathord}{lettersA}{147}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rT}{\mathord}{lettersA}{148}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rU}{\mathord}{lettersA}{149}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rV}{\mathord}{lettersA}{150}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rW}{\mathord}{lettersA}{151}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rX}{\mathord}{lettersA}{152}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rY}{\mathord}{lettersA}{153}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\m@thbbch@rZ}{\mathord}{lettersA}{154}

\long\def\DoLongFutureLet #1#2#3#4{%
   \def\@FutureLetDecide{#1#2\@FutureLetToken
      \def\@FutureLetNext{#3}\else
      \def\@FutureLetNext{#4}\fi\@FutureLetNext}
   \futurelet\@FutureLetToken\@FutureLetDecide}
\def\DoFutureLet #1#2#3#4{\DoLongFutureLet{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}
\def\@EachCharacter{\DoFutureLet{\ifx}{\@EndEachCharacter}%
   {\@EachCharacterDone}{\@PickUpTheCharacter}}
\def\m@keCharacter#1{\csname\F@ntPrefix#1\endcsname}
\def\@PickUpTheCharacter#1{\m@keCharacter{#1}\@EachCharacter}
\def\@EachCharacterDone \@EndEachCharacter{}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\varmathbb}[1]{\gdef\F@ntPrefix{m@thbbch@r}%
  \@EachCharacter #1\@EndEachCharacter}
\makeatother
```